# Converting bytes from device to decimal in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://cylab.be/blog/92/measure-ambient-temperature-with-temper-and-linux to get the TEMPer USB sensor to measure ambient temperature so that I can incorporate it into a Perl script that alerts me of a room's ambient temperature. In the tutorial's example they convert the following bytes of data from the device:

```
Response from device (8 bytes):
     80 80 0b 92   4e 20 00 00
```

to:

```
In the response, the Bytes 3 and 4 (so 0b 92) indicate the ambient temperature:

0b 92 converted into decimal is 2932
2932 divided by 100 is 29.32 C
```

Does anyone know how I can use Perl to translate such bytes of data to a decimal and thus to celsius temperature?

Comment: *"0b 92 converted into decimal is 2932"* - No, it's 2962. You can use `unpack("n","\x0b\x92")` for the convertion.

Comment: ...2932[10] would be b74[16]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl's [hex](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex) function can translate hexadecimal numbers in text to Perl numbers, which you can then represent any way that you like:

```
my $string = '0b92';
my $number = hex($string);
print $number;  # 2962
```

But, it sounds like you may be reading raw data from a device, and that the number you want is in two octets. Read those and turn them into a Perl number with unpack (with the appropriate format that respects the octet order):

```
my $buffer;
read $fh, $buffer, 2;
my $number = unpack 'S>', $buffer;
```